# Append time zone information to a timestamp column

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

My data is stored without a time zone, in IST (changing this is not an option for now).

```
select 
  some_date as t0,
  some_date AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata' as t1, 
  date_add('minute', -330, some_date) AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata' as t2
from my_table limit 1;

t0: 2016-03-27 09:52:33.000    
t1: 2016-03-27 15:22:33.000 Asia/Kolkata
t2: 2016-03-27 09:52:33.000 Asia/Kolkata
```

What I want is `t2`, however the way I've obtained it is poor. Is there a better way to append time zone information to a timestamp column?

Comment: Did you try non-legacy timestamp semantics, as introduced under https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/7122?

Comment: Also, what would `cast(some_date as timestamp with time zone)` print in your setup and your session?

Comment: `cast(some_date as timestamp with time zone)` returns `2016-03-27 09:52:33.000 UTC`

Comment: Is your session zone UTC? Did you try changing session zone? With the issue I linked being done, everything would be easier...

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I have been googling, and I cannot find anything regarding session zones in athena, any advice?

Comment: Session zone is sent to Presto by the client library, there is no SQL statement to change the zone. I don't know Athena's client library(-ies). Would it make sense to you to try standalone Presto and corresponding client libraries? You can use e.g. https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07DKV5659 to bring up Presto cluster of desired size easily.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen unfortunately the system is large and in production, an infrastructure change would be too much work to improve a small timezone issue.